# How to create a Calendar in Android Application

Tags: android

We are developing an Android application and we need to add a event calendar in our app.

Is there any widget or something that we can use? Something like this:

```
homescreen > icon_calendar > calendar
```

Comment: Are you need this in on your device or emulator?

Comment: same, thanks to this http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/wiki/HowToUse but we have a problem, we need to make that calendar editable so the users can use it as their event calendar. Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's called [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), and it's pretty easy to use. However it's only available starting API 11 (Android 3.0)

Comment: sorry for that, i'm a newbie. btw Thanks :)